# iOS - Performing several simultaneous animations with autolayout

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I want to perform two simultaneous movement animations. First animation on `firstView` starts immediately. Second animation on `secondView`, starts after a slight delay while the first animation is still running. `secondView` constraint is related to `firstView`. The code works perfectly well on iOS 8.

`firstView` and `secondView` are subviews of `view`

```
view  
    |--- firstView  
    |--- secondView
```

Code:

```
UIView *firstView = ...;
UIView *secondView = ...;    

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:firstView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.topLayoutGuide attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.15 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:secondView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:firstView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

On iOS 7, once the second `layoutIfNeeded` is called, the first animations stops and only the seconds animation animates.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews instead of calling layoutIfNeeded directly. Although that does basically the same, maybe it helps.

Comment: @Kim Tried that already. Didn't help.

Comment: If you don't find a solution with UIView animations, you could try UIKit dynamics instead. There's a good tutorial here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50197/uikit-dynamics-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I ended up doing the animation in a 2-step (3-step, depends how you count) solution. First add the constraints without calling `layoutIfNeeded`. Then update the `firtView` and `secondView` frames. Lastly call `layoutIfNeeded` in the completion block of the last animation.

Code:

```
UIView *firstView = ...;
UIView *secondView = ...;    

/* first step */
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:firstView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.topLayoutGuide attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint1];
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:secondView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:firstView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint2];

/* second step */
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    CGRect firstViewFrame = CGRectMake(...); // set frame according to constaint1
    firstView.frame = firstViewFrame;
}];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.15 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    CGRect secondViewFrame = CGRectMake(...); // set frame according to constaint2
    secondView.frame = secondViewFrame;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    /* second and a half step */
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Two important notes**:

1. You need to call layoutIfNeeded within the animation block. Apple
   actually recommends you call it once before the animation block to
   ensure that all pending layout operations have been completed.
2. You need to call it specifically on the parent view (e.g.
   self.view), not the child view that has the constraints attached to
   it. Doing so will update all constrained views, including animating
   other views that might be constrained to the view that you changed
   the constraint of (e.g. View B is attached to the bottom of View A
   and you just changed View A's top offset and you want View B to
   animate with it).

You must do it like this:

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];

NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:firstView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.topLayoutGuide attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

Comment: That's exactly what my sample code in the question does.

Comment: Please check i have changed position of adding constraints.

Comment: It won't work for multiple animations. It will cause all of them to be performed immediately without any delay between them.

Comment: I am using it the same way and its working same way. Also follow the same for second view. And have you tried it using this way? @mrvincenzo